# Why can't I access stored procedures on a linked MSDE 8.x server?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure on a linked MSDE 8.x server by running the following SQL against the parent SQL Server 2000 instance...

```
DECLARE @RC int

EXECUTE @RC = [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[LINKED_SERVER_DATABASE].[dbo].[STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME]

GO
```

...but I get this error message:

```
Msg 7411, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Server 'LINKED_SERVER_NAME' is not configured for RPC.
```

Comment: what versions of sql server are you connecting to?

Comment: SQL 2000. (re-wrote the question to better explain the problem)

Comment: what do you mean when you say you can't see the stored procs?  you mean in management studio?  please provide an example of the call your making to an msde db sproc & the response/error, so as I might have a chance in figuring out whats going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio:

1. Right-click the MSDE linked server instance and choose [Properties]
2. Select [Server Options]
3. Make sure that the [RPC] and [RPC Out] properties are set to [TRUE]

(in my case they were both set to FALSE)

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  It's not a permissions issue, it's a case of RPC not being enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can store credentials in a powershell session using get-credentials but I'm guessing that's not what you're after.

Powershell runs in the context of whoever startet it (like all windows executeables), so for SQL Server operations I'd just use integrated windows security for the connection, and then assign the correct SQL Permissions to the user/service account that you set up to be running the scripts. That way you use the security model in WIndows and won't have to make your own :-)